# "Disgusting" as the Chinese would say it

Tags: translation, hong-kong, taiwanese

How to say "Disgusting." in Chinese (the Taiwanese way, and Hong Kong way) about the defilement of a nation's culture & traditions? I need the harshest word for 'disgusting' possible.

Answer (score 2):

for the word "disgusting" A simple search can yield many results:

> 肉酸 http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/1431/
>
> 肉麻 http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/2054/
>
> 反胃 http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/13997/
>
> 嘔心 http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/15164/
>
> 鶻突 http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/1310/

However,

> *about the defilement of a nation's culture & traditions*

I think the word you are looking for is "shameful"

> 可恥 http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/46203/

Answer (score 1):

One word that pops in mind for Chinese would be 無恥 which is shameful.

Here's an old movie clip, showing the time when Nationalist from China invaded Taiwan and forced everyone, including school teachers and children to speak Chinese. Those who spoke Taiwanese had to wear a sign saying they will speak Chinese. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_IVfqlpPPbM

Words seen in this clip are
at 2:50 playful words that children call each other when they are calling each other disguisting
邋遢鬼 (I have heard it pronounced in Taiwanese as 垃圾鬼), 骯髒鬼

at 4.14 
閉嘴、不像話、夭壽死嬰仔你 translated in clip as -> shut up, you short life little bastard you

I think what you're trying to say is what is spoken by the teacher from 4:14 and afterwards. Those are common phrases that adults use to 教訓 naughty little kids.

Comment: *無恥 which is shameful.*  -- It is shameless

Comment: 邋遢 or 骯髒 means "dirty"

Comment: Thanks @tang ho for pointing this out. Using shameless as a way to insult someone for having no shame vs being shameful. I think there is some subtle differences that depending on context of how it is used, can give off different feelings

Answer (score 1):

**恶心** / **噁心**

[junyiacademy](https://www.junyiacademy.org/root/english-vocabulary1/dragon-book1-lesson2-new/v/dD_itrx5yK0)

> disgust: 使感到噁心, disgusting, 令人噁心的, disgusted, 感到噁心的。
>
> [image: one]
>
> [image: two]

There's also a video here explaning: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dD_itrx5yK0